# Change UIBarButton Identifier on runtime

Tags: xamarin.ios

i want to change the Identifier of my UIBarButton when the value from my slider has changed. I tried it that way:

```
var button = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save);
this.Pad_btnClose = null;
this.Pad_btnClose = button;
```

But it doesnt work. I also tried it that way:

```
this.Pad_btnClose = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save);
```

doesn´t work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting that variable (or outlet, you don't say which) isn't going to remove the UIBarButtonItem from the screen.

In order to do that, you must create an outlet for the UIToolbar, then call:

```
yourToolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] { yourNewButtonItem };
```

Or if you want it to animate:

```
yourToolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { yourNewButtonItem }, true);
```

This will overwrite the list of button items in the toolbar on the screen.